# Organization Integration on Dynamics 365 crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I have 2 org on my crm on-premises system, I want when case created in first org , case with same data create at second org , how can i achieve that?

I 've tried to do plugin triggered when created case connect to another org and create case like that,but this didn't work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research or search for related topics on SO. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have working on similar tasks in the past and here is how I addressed such scenarios:

- I developed and hosted some kind of webservice - implementation here might be different. Here is one of the examples how it might be implemented - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api
- inside that webservice when the payload that contains incident's information is received I connected to the "Destination" system using tools from SDK - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/build-windows-client-applications-xrm-tools and created the incident and any related required information - in your case it will be a customer (contact or account)
- in the source system I developed a plugin to handle create and/or update of the incident, built the payload with the data I needed to send to the destination system and called the webservice I developed in previous steps

Comment: Thank you so much, will it work if I only use web service? I already have case controller web Api for source org, so my question can I just edit create case endpoint and others to connect to destination org and do same action there?

Comment: That might work. Anyways you will need either a trigger or a scheduled job that will query for new/updated cases in the source org and update that data in the destination org.